# not able to create new react-native project

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I am trying to create a react-native-cli project by command "react-native init projectname"  but it is getting stuck by showing this line in command line after some time "info adding required Dev dependencies"

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
info Adding required dev dependencies

Comment: try `npm clean`

Comment: if still doesn't work, upgrade or downgrade your npm to version 4.6.1 it is the most stable version of npm

Answer (score 1):

fsevents is optional dependency and its used only if you use macOS env, and this is not error its only warning.